# How to show particular div section when I select the dropdown option by clicking the submit button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to showcase the particular div section when I choose the select option from dropdown and I have written below code but that's not working anyone can please help on that. how to do actual requirement is when I select the option from select and clicking by submit button then only I want to show the particular div section .

```js
 

        function checkTenant(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var drpdownvalue = document.getElementById("tenentval").value;
            
            alert(drpdownvalue)
            if (drpdownvalue.value == "one" || drpdownvalue.value == "two") {
                //alert(drpdownvalue)
                document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
                //alert(drpdownvalue)

            } else {
                document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";

            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
        integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select class="form-control" id="tenentval">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option value="one">1</option>
                        <option value="two">2</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" onclick="checkTenant(event)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="row div1" style="display: none;" id="ifYes">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="div1" style="width: 100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #f00"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this condition is never met because on `var drpdownvalue = document.getElementById("tenentval").value`; you already get the value.

So when you try to get `drpdownvalue.value` , it's always `undefined`.

```
if (drpdownvalue.value == "one" || drpdownvalue.value == "two")
```

Just use

```
if (drpdownvalue == "one" || drpdownvalue == "two")
```

Comment: it's a great explanation I just got it point now and thank you very much